# How do you add a title to a legend in Flot

Tags: flot

I want to add a title to the legend box in Flot?  For example, if my legend shows different Products, I want the title above the legend box to say "Products".

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat hacky, but you can do it like this:

```
var $legend = $('#chart > div.legend'); // replace #chart with the id from your div
var $legendTitle = $legend.find('div').first();
$legendTitle.html('Products').height($legendTitle.height() + 15);
$legend.find('table').first().css('top', $legendTitle.position().top + 15);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out and let you know how it goes. Amazing that there is not a built in way to do this!  :)